# Can you access an object through two layers of assemblies?

Tags: c#, assemblies, encapsulation, class-library

I have a public class, MainObject that is in a class library (dll), for this example we will call it BaseLibrary.

I have a higher level class library that references the BaseLibrary to gain access to it's members. We will call this one DeviceLibrary.

I then have a Windows Forms Project, DeviceControl, in which I have added a reference to DeviceLibrary.

If I need to use a MainObject object, how do I do it? I know I can just add a second reference in the DeviceControl project to the BaseLibrary but I am just wondering if there is another way to access it through the DeviceLibrary? I am not sure what the laws of encapsulation dictate here...

Answer (score 3):

You *have* to add the reference.  If you don't then the compiler will complain and tell you to add the reference.  Using Reflection hacks should be a very distant second choice, it merely makes your code slow and still doesn't remove the runtime dependency on the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Any type to which you refer in your code must be part of a directly referenced assembly.

Although usually not practical, you can use the `MainObject` without directly referring to it by using a `System.Object` reference instead and using Reflection to call its members. In C# 4.0 you can probably just use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
dynamic x = MethodReturningAMainObject();
x.Foo(); //this will be compiled to use reflection to find "Foo"
```

Aside from using a dynamic or `object` reference, you can use any exposed base class or interface that applies to `MainObject`.

Comment: You _can_ use dynamic, but you (almost definitely) don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to alter the contents of the library assemblies (i.e. it's your code), then you could either:

1. Move `MainObject` into a separate reference assembly and have any of the existing assemblies reference it.  This works well if `MainObject` is not actually dependent on the other contents of BaseLibrary.
2. Extract an interface from `MainObject` and place *that* in a reference library that every other assembly can reference.  Then is you code to the interface, you only need a reference to the new reference library.

If you can't alter the contents of the library assemblies, you could resort to writing a wrapper object for MainObject, with it's own interface and extract the interface to a reference library as in option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This doesn't fully address your question.

Typically in a N-Tier design the "Models" span all layers. Here is one chart that I reference when designing: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/cc700340.fig01_L(en-us).gif

I'm not sure what your BaseLibrary includes, but it seems like you may have to reference it from your DeviceLibrary.

Comment: Useful diagram, have you got a link to the original context that came from?